# control dimensions of custom alert dialog in different screen orientations

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, screen-orientation

I want to set dimensions for my custom alert dialog, based on screen orientation. My intention is to swap height and width values to keep the box look like being the same size, yet handled various screen sizes of various devices, thanks to Android fragmentation it seems difficult to achieve the same effect on all devices. Android's auto-resizing seems weird to me.

**Portrait**:

```
alertDialog.width=screen.width*0.8
alertDialog.height=screen.height=0.5
```

**Landscape**:

```
alertDialog.width=screen.width*0.5;
alertDialog.height=screen.height*0.8
```

Please note that the Custom Alert Dialog must use the same code and support Android versions from JellyBean (at least 4.2) to Nougat (7).

i am using android.support.v7.AlertDialog (the latest available thing)

i assume android.app.Dialog should be avoided now (being old)

Also, i need a black border and white background for the same. i am unable to achieve same effect on all devices, (i need transparency for rounded corners)

i have used ***android:windowMinWidthMajor*** and ***android:windowMinWidthMinor*** but they affect both layouts (portrait and landscape) and seem to be ignored if content does not fit within the specified constraints.

I wish there was ***android:windowMaxWidthMinor*** & ***android:windowMaxWidthMajor***

Comment: You might want to look into the DialogTheme since it controls the presentation of the dialog, including the transparent shadow and white background. 50% width is quite narrow for a dialog, but Android will resize your dialog for you anyway. Best bet is to change the theme and use dimensions to control width. Alternatively, you have to wait until the dialog is added to the view but not yet displayed to change the height & width.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that I've used for resizing specific views on a page:

```
myView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(() -> {
    item.height = myView.getHeight();
});
```

Applying it to what you want to do:

```
myView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(() -> {
    LayoutParams params = (get the layout params according to the layout);
    params.width = myView.getWidth() * 0.5;
    params.height = myView.getHeight() * 0.8;
    myView.setLayoutParams(params);
});
```

You have to use the listener because the object will be added to the view tree, will be measured and prepared for display, but won't yet be displayed, so you can change its dimensions before it is visible.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**:

I could achieve it by setting `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` for my Layout. and layout values for each component in the style to

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

to achieve the center alignment.

XML Code available at https://github.com/computingfreak/CFTest/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/alert_popup.xml

Java Code available at
https://github.com/computingfreak/CFTest/blob/master/app/src/main/java/net/cf/sms/cftest/MainActivity.java

I wonder this line of code is redundant

```
view.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
```

and thus left it to Android System to decide dimensions and resizing based on content. It works for my case, but will fail in case of long text, maybe some kind of Scroll Layout will help. Cheers!